# Symbolic link to other device

Tags: linux, symbolic-link

If I have a symbolic link in a directory on a physical drive that points to tmpfs RAM partition, and I write to the symbolic link will the physical experience an writing?

I'm going to being down a large amount of data writes and I want it in RAM instead of taxing my SSD

Comment: this question is better on unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

If the symbolic link is IN a directory then you'll be writing TO that directory. If that directory is in RAM (shmfs/tmpfs) than you'll be writing to RAM.

It doesn't matter what the link is pointing to.